# Chatter - Can conversations that mention objects appear in the object's Chatter feed?

Tags: chatter, feeditem, chatter-feed, chatter-groups

We are exploring the use of Chatter to replace some business comms that are currently use Slack.

If I mention an object (e.g. an Opportunity) on a chatter feed, can the conversation be displayed on the Object's Chatter feed?

[image]
[image]

Am I naive to think that would be quite useful functionality? Am I missing something?

Comment: Was trying to replicate this in my org and was wondering how you could @mention the Opportunityname in your public group.

Answer (score 1):

That is how the "slash mention" currently works. There's this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PYwyQAG) asking for what you're thinking it should do.

I did see this workaround suggested by a comment in the idea

> Create a dedicated Chatter Group and then @tag the group instead of another record. Groups do have a related Records list

That workaround only works if that fits your use case (a group flagging records for some purpose). It doesn't seem to meet your need in terms of ideal experience as sales user would have to go to a record and then tag the sales group.

In terms of a custom/programmatic workaround, you're left with having to use the [Connect API](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_chatter_rest_api.pdf) which means, for apex, you'd have to look into using [ConnectAPIHelper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper) once it's been posted to copy it to the record's feed. I wouldn't recommend this approach, but it's possible (details below)

---

Within the Connect API, you can get the [MessageSegments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_output_msg_seg.htm) within the feed elements and it contains a [ConnectApi.EntityLinkSegment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_output_entityLinkSeg.htm) which has a [ConnectApi.Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_output_reference.htm) that has the `URL` and `Id` to the record where you could then copy the contents and post to the record's feed. Problem is, within the FeedItem trigger or even querying it in a scheduled apex, the body doesn't return as ConnectApiHelper expects so you need to rely on [ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElement()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm).

Comment: Thanks, Kris. I agree on the workaround - I don't think it's feasible for users to tag each Opportunity record.